# Vault Injector with externalVaultAddr permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to connect Vault injector from my AWS Kubernetes cluster and login using the `injector.externalVaultAddr="http://my-aws-instance-ip:8200"`

Installation:

```sh
helm install vault \
    --set='injector.externalVaultAddr=http://my-aws-instance-ip:8200' \
    /path/to/my/vault-helm
```

After following the necessary steps here: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/injecting-vault-secrets-into-kubernetes-pods-via-a-sidecar/ and customising this:

```sh
vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
   token_reviewer_jwt="$(cat kube_token_from_my_k8s_cluster)" \
   kubernetes_host="$KUBERNETES_HOST:443" \
   kubernetes_ca_cert=@downloaded_ca_crt_from_my_k8s_cluster.crt
```

Now, after adding the deployment app.yaml and adding the vault annotations to read the `secret/helloworld`, it doesn't start my pod and shows this error on the container `vault-agent-init`

```sh
NAME                                READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
app-aaaaaaa-bbbb                    1/1     Running    0          34m
app-aaaaaaa-cccc                    0/2     Init:0/1   0          34m
vault-agent-injector-xxxxxx-zzzzz   1/1     Running    0          35m
```

```sh
$ kubectl logs -f app-aaaaaaa-cccc -c vault-agent-init
...
URL: PUT http://my-aws-instance-ip:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
Code: 403. Errors:

* permission denied" backoff=2.769289902
```

I have also tried manually doing it in my local:

```sh
$ export VAULT_ADDR="http://my-aws-instance-ip:8200"
$ curl --request POST \
       --data "{\"role\": \"myapp\", \"jwt\": \"$(cat kube_token_from_my_k8s_cluster)\"}" \
       $VAULT_ADDR/v1/auth/kubernetes/login

# RESPONSE OUTPUT
{"errors":["permission denied"]}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `VAULT_ADDR` being set to `https://`? Also could you provide output of `$ vault status`.

Comment: Thanks @Crou, I haven't tried setting it to https yet as I didn't implement secured connection to our vault server yet. 

`vault status` is good. I can't paste the actual status message because this comment area doesn't allow me add code section.

Comment: @Tami Pangadi- were you able to resolve the issue. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try curling the Kubernetes API-service with the values you used to set up Kubernetes auth in Vault.

```
vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
    token_reviewer_jwt="$TOKEN_REVIEW_JWT" \
    kubernetes_host="$KUBE_HOST" \
    kubernetes_ca_cert="$KUBE_CA_CERT"

curl --cacert <ca-cert-file> -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN_REVIEW_JWT" $KUBE_HOST
```

If that doesn't work Vault won't be able to communicate with the cluster to get tokens verified.

I had this problem when trying to integrate Vault with a Rancher managed cluster, $KUBE_HOST was pointing to the rancher proxy so I needed to change it to the IP of the cluster and extract token and ca cert from the service account I was using.

Comment: Would you mind giving a few more details on how you extracted token and ca.cert from the service account instead of k8s?

Comment: You can extract it from the secret tied to the service account:
```kubectl get secret/<name-of-secret> -o yaml```